# Turn on english keyboard layout entering my profile

Tags: keyboard-layout

I'm on Ubuntu 17.10. After removing English language from keyboard layouts. I can't use it somehow to enter my password. Any shortcuts don't work. Screen keyboard displays english letters, but don't typing. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What shortcuts have you tried?

Comment: @pomsky ctrl+shift, alt+shift

Comment: Try super+space, ctrl+super+space etc.

Comment: Doesn't work. Actually my shortcut is alt+shift. I've just removed english layout from the list.

Comment: The most interesting thing is that screen keyboard has English layout and all animations are fine while pressing, but it doesn't work.

Comment: What does the command `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources` output?

Comment: Also, [this bug comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-docs/+bug/1725676/comments/7) might help.